# Can analog input be read from the headphone jack using C# and NAudio on any new MacBook pro models?

Tags: c#, macos, input, naudio

I was just wondering if at all or to what extent you could read analog data coming from the headphone jack on new MacBook pro models. I was using that Square card reader and thought it would interesting to try to make it work for laptops as a simple card reader. Is it at all possible to read data this way using C# and NAudio?

Answer (score 0):

You can not connect any headphone jack to a source. It has to be a line input or microphone input. Some laptops have combo-jacks, that are software controlled. Then it is either an input or an output. If you connect a voltage source to the headphone jack, you risk to damage your equipment.